# How to scan all token transfers on both ethereum and matic?

Tags: blockchain, etherscan, web3.py

I have the following code that uses the etherscan API to read for the most recent transfers for a particular contract-address on the Ethereum chain. I need to do the same, but on the Matic chain. From what I can see the etherscan API would not support this.

```
import etherscan.accounts as accounts


""" The following is an example code that continuously checks the transactions for the Tether token and prints
the most recent 3. """

key = ''  # Insert your own Etherscan API_KEY

address = '0xdac...'  # Address of coin we want to read
api = accounts.Account(address=address, api_key=key)


while(True):  # For now loop infinitely
    page = api.get_transaction_page(page=1, offset=3, sort='desc')  # Get the latest 3 transactions

    # Print them
    print(page[0])
    print(page[1])
    print(page[2])
    print('=============')
```

Is there an API or way to scan both Ethereum and Matic chains?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an API or way to scan both Ethereum and Matic chains?

The official block explorer for Polygon is [MaticVigil](https://maticvigil.com/docs/), which provides an API gateway similar to the services you've used on Etherscan.

However, given that it's only recently been released, you'll have to sign up ([here](https://rpc.maticvigil.com/)) to get an invite before you can access it.

(There are other paid services, such as [QuikNode](https://blog.quiknode.io/polygon-matic-is-now-live-on-quiknode-api/).)